# How do I set a constraint or limit to my application so I won't delete a record that is currently in use?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this app with multiple forms. One of which manages the entire personnel record and then some of the fields that are required to be filled up on that form was associated or linked to other forms (job, location, etc.). So what I wanted to do is that, once I've set a (say for example) job title on the job field of personnel record, I shouldn't be able to delete that job title on the job form since that record was currently in use.

Comment: You should add some of the relevant code you've tried already.

Comment: I tried checking for duplicates by using SELECT before the actual DELETE process to no avail.

Comment: It looks like you should read about `Foreign Keys`.

Comment: how did you fix it?Any updates

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a locking mechanism.

Every time a database record (of whichever transactional entity), is opened in your application for editing purposes, you should lock it in the DB (have lock column - BIT - with user info).
This will ensure that any other user will only be able to view the record but not edit, until the 1st/original user unlocks it.

This will require some amount code strengthening, apt transaction isolation level set in you application's architecture.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a new column to your databse '*`usage_flag`*'.

When '`usage_flag`' value equals

- 1 :- Should not delete.
- 0 :- Of course you can delete.

You should set this flag to 1 whenever you are adding something(say Job title).
Hope this helps